# Where to extract methods from controller (controller is too many lines)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

In the create method of my Document controller, I have an if statement that checks params, and based on each of those conditions, it creates a certain type of document. However, I have too many lines, so i would like to extract all these methods elsewhere and call them in the controller. After reading and looking around, I am still unsure of the best place to move these. What is the best way to deal with this in Rails?

I have trimmed down and simplified/renamed the code so that it easier to read and to focus on the overall idea

app/controllers/documents_controller.rb

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  #index, show, update here

  def create
    location = Location.find(params[:id] 

    if params[:report].present?
      create_report(location)

    elsif params[:faq].present?
      create_faq(location)

    elsif params[:story].present?
      create_story(location)

    elsif params[:guide].present?
      create_guide
    end

    # a few other lines here
  end

  private
  # some methods here unrelated to creating document subtypes, but the ones below creating subtypes of documents are the ones i need to extract out 

  def create_report(location)
    @document =
      Event::CreateReport.call(
        # what we pass here changes based on the document subtype, but i just left them all the same 
        location: location,
        created_by: user,
        date: params[:date],
        text: params[:text],
        guide_stuff: 'a few more lines to pass unique subtype stuff here'
      )

    Notification::NewDocuments.new(location, user).send!
  end

  def create_faq(location)
    @document =
      Patient::CreateFaq.call(
        location: location,
        created_by: user,
        date: params[:date],
        text: params[:text],
        faq_stuff: 'unique subtype stuff here'
      )

    Notification::NewDocuments.new(location, user).send!
  end

  def create_story(location)
    @document =
      Event::CreateStory.call(
        location: location,
        created_by: user,
        date: params[:date],
        text: params[:text],
        story_stuff: 'a few more lines to pass unique subtype stuff here'
      )

    Notification::NewDocuments.new(location, user).send!
  end

  def create_guide
    @document =
      Event::CreateGuide.call(
        location: location,
        created_by: user,
        date: params[:date],
        text: params[:text],
        guide_stuff: 'a few more lines to pass unique subtype stuff here'
      )
  end
end
```

Comment: This question might be a better fit at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @spickermann This question would be off-topic on Code Review as it is missing context. In the future please link to the help center when recommending Code Review. Take, `This may be on-topic on Code Review. Please check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there.`

Comment: There is always only one of those params present?  There is never multiple params that could be present, correct?

Comment: @spickermann I appreciate the suggestion, but I am more asking a general question about what is the best practice for this kind of thing (ie where to move the methods, file structure, etc). My code is stripped down to demonstrate the question easier.. i dont see how this question fits the need for actual code review.

Comment: @RockwellRice that is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a type of opinion question that doesn't really fit on StackOverflow, since they are highly subjective and can devolve. I can't lay off an honest question, though, so without proffering an opinion here are a couple of things to consider/research:

1. Service Objects. Some Rails developers swear by them, some believe they are overused and possibly cause male-pattern baldness. See [this overview](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) for how they work and [this blog](https://avdi.codes/service-objects/) for the opposite view.
2. You might consider whether some of the operations you are doing need to be synchronous in the request cycle or whether they might be candidates to be `ActiveJob`s (which are essentially a different kind of service object).
3. A lot of new Rails developers tend to get fixated on models as persistent, but there's no harm in having non-persistent models that encapsulate behaviour.
4. If you've got a chunk of re-usable functional code that just doesn't fit in a 'model' or 'service object', there's no harm in dropping that into a module and calling it like a function/class method.

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate it. My apologies, I didn't realize it was that open ended. I have chosen to try the service objects route.